# errors when installing riscv-tools

Tags: riscv

I try to install the riscv-tools following the instructions from http://riscv.org/software-tools/. However, I meet problems when I build riscv-isa-sim and the error information is as follows:
[Error information when build the riscv-isa-sim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MW0w.png)

I am working on Ubuntu-15.10 and thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you don't use gcc-5?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 ./build.sh
```

In case you are using the default version of GCC of Ubuntu 15.10 use only

```
./build.sh
```

Also, did you install all the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you clone the riscv-tools specified in rocket-chip.

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```